# Redirect Loop ONLY in safari using htaccess when trying to redirect http to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I don't know why this is happening, but when I visit my site from any other browser other than safari, it redirects me to the https version. However, if I visit the same site using safari (on iPhone, mac, or iPad), it says there is a redirect loop.

My htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

Options -Indexes


</IfModule>
```

I don't know why this is happening. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it by using this instead.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}  !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Any idea why `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` didn't do the job? Saw the same but only on MacBook, not on i-Devices and as soon as I proxied the traffic through my Windows machine [Fiddler], the issue was gone. Haven't had the time to try it with a local Apache, yet, which I would be able to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

Options -Indexes


</IfModule>
```

Replace **example.com** with your domain name in HTTP_HOST string pattern.

Comment: Clear your browser cache.